# Download files and save in application folder for android version higher than 5 (lolipop)

Tags: android

I'm working with a application who use downloading mp3 files from web with URL and set them in folder created in external storage ,it was work with version 5 (lolipop) ,but when I test it with version 8 and 10 ,this not work!

this is downloading code:

```
String surl="https://media.sd.ma/assabile/recitations_7892537823/mp3/saad-el-ghamidi-001-al-fatiha-204-9244.mp3";

    try{
        URL url=new URL(surl);
        URLConnection conexion=url.openConnection();
      
        conexion.connect();
        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
      
        File apkStorage = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +"apk_stokage");
        if (!apkStorage.exists()) {
            apkStorage.mkdir();
        }
        outputFile=new File(apkStorage,title+".mp3");
        if (!outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.createNewFile();
            Log.e("apk_stokage","File Created");
        }
        String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/apk_stokage/";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);//Get OutputStream for NewFile Location
        InputStream is= new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];//Set buffer type
        int len1 = 0;//init length
        long total=0;
        while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            total+=len1;
            publishProgress((int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);//Write new file
        }
      //  fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        is.close();

       // path2=outputFile.getPath();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Well what does 'not work' from all those code lines? Which line exactly? Exceptions? Errors? Look in Logcat.

Comment: Please put log statements in catch blocks.

Comment: `apkStorage.mkdir();` check the return value as it might fail to create that directory. If it fails then stop. Better try to create the directory before you start download. Adapt your code to do so.

Comment: `String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/apk_stokage/";` Remove that line as you are not using it. (Which is good).

Comment: And please adapt the subject of your post. Dont shout.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a library to do that with any file type and size. you can take a look to [the library](https://github.com/rembertime/download-worker-android). The downloaded files will be saved on download directory. Any bug fixes and improvements are welcome

Comment: thanks for answer my question !                                                                                                                                           Is there a way to move the downloaded files from download diretory to my app stokage ?                     or can i costumize the directory of downloaded files ? because i have necessary to save it in independent directory ?

Comment: no, you cant do that with the current version but i can add this behavior and release a new version if you need